# Test for undefined function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

So Safari keeps yelling at me for one specific error.

I'm trying to use Google Maps API and call `map.getCenter();`. However sometimes, this happens before the `map` has been fully loaded.

So instead in my function I test for an `undefined` call like this:

```
if (map.getCenter() != undefined)
```

But that still errors out because I guess it doesn't even like making the call just to test the if the result is `undefined` or not?

Can I get some help here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
if (typeof map !== 'undefined' && map.getCenter) {
   // code for both map and map.getCenter exists
} else {
  // if they dont exist
}
```

This is the right way to check for existence of a function.. Calling the function to test its existence will result in an error.

**UPDATE:** Snippet updated.

Comment: If you're not going to be type-strict (`!==`), you may as well just write `if (!map.getCenter)`.

Comment: I will give this a shot when I get home. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nope. Gives me 'ReferenceError: map is not defined' when I run your example in smjs console.

Comment: could you please tell me, why my condition work without single quote at the undefined

Comment: Note to future seekers: if(typeof FooFunc === 'undefined') { function FooFunc(){} } will not define the function in Safari.

Answer (score 49):

I actually prefer something along these lines.

```
if(typeof myfunc == 'function') { 
    myfunc(); 
}
```

Just because something isn't undefined doesn't make it a function.

Comment: Except that in this case I guess that you want to define a function if it doesn't exist `if(typeof myfunc !== 'function') { myfunc(); }`

Comment: @Henrik Your comment code should look like, `if(typeof myfunc !== 'function') { myfunc = function(){.....}; }`

Answer (score 5):

Technically you should be testing if `map` is undefined, not `map.getCenter()`. You can't call a function on an undefined reference.

However, [Google's own tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html) suggests that you invoke your JavaScript that accesses the API in a body.onload handler, so that you do not attempt to reference anything until all of the remote .js files are loaded - are you doing this? This would solve the problem permanently, rather than failing cleanly when your JavaScript executes prior to loading the API.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (typeof map.getCenter !== 'undefined')
```

Won't throw an error.

So, better yet, `if (typeof map.getCenter === 'function') map.getCenter();`

Answer (score 1):

I have been in the habit recently of using the typeof operator to test for things and types. It returns the type as a string which I think avoids some response type confusion.

```
if( typeof map.getCenter != 'undefined') ...
```

I'm not sure if it's more correct, but I find good results with this process.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an optional chaining operator that does exactly this.

The optional chaining (?.) operator accesses an object's property or calls a function. If the object accessed or function called using this operator is undefined or null, the expression short circuits and evaluates to undefined instead of throwing an error.

```
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);
// Expected output: undefined

console.log(adventurer.someNonExistentMethod?.());
// Expected output: undefined
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

You should be testing whether `map` is undefined. In your current check your are still trying to execute the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that map.getCenter() is always a function, it's sufficient to just use this check:

```
if (map.getCenter) {
      var x = map.getCenter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The worked solution for me is `try and catch`,

```
const stopPropagation = (e) => {
    try {
        e.stopPropagation();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error with stopPropagation: " + err.error);
    }
}

const triggerClick = (e) => {
    stopPropagation(e);
};
```